# What javascript command is this?

Tags: javascript, conditional-statements

I remember a command that checks that a given condition is true, otherwise it stops the script. It was one word, starting with a, i think starting with att.. and it was just that word, the condition in parentheses, and the semicolon. I've googled everything I can think of and cannot find it!

Comment: Sounds like an `assert`.  I don't believe that javascript has a built in `assert`, but it should be simple to write one.

Comment: Yeah, reminds me of assert too. But that's `<cstdlib>`, not JavaScript.

Comment: That was it. It may not have been javascript.. but thanks! If you want to post it as an answer I will accept.

Comment: @Imp `assert` exists in countless languages, not just in C++.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if there's something built in natively to JavaScript but have you tried looking at this?

http://aymanh.com/9-javascript-tips-you-may-not-know#assertion

Answer (score 0):

`if(!condition) return;` //for a single assertion statement

Furthermore, you might mean "assert." Google it with javascript for a couple of reads on the subject.

Comment: if(!condition)return; would stop at that line and return from wherever the code was running, but it would not prevent execution of the script correct?

Comment: You are correct, but I wanted to put more emphasis on the second part of my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for a function with the semantics of `assert(condition)`, i.e., throw an exception if `condition` is false.  javascript does not contain a native `assert` like function, but you could certainly implement it yourself.  A bit of searching will yield some good results.

```
function assert(condition) {
  condition || throw "assert failed"
}
```

You can spruce it up a bit as needed, but that's the basic idea.